# Why ObservableCollection doesn't actualize?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am writing an application, that work on big amount of data and then visualize them on a graph. Calculations take long time, so I'd like programm to work like that:

1. Calculating point.
2. Adding calculated point to the graph
3. Calculating next point
4. Adding calculated point to the graph
   etc.

However my application works differently:

1. Calculating all point (takes huge amount of time)
2. Display everything at once.

I don't understand why it go this way, since I use OnPropertyChanged method after adding each point to the graph.

Code-behind - graph class:

```
public class graph : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class pnt
    {
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }

        public pnt(double _x, double _y) { x = _x; y = _y; }
    }

    public double maxy { get; set; }
    public double scale_y { get { return 200 / maxy; } }
    public double width { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<double> values;
    public ObservableCollection<punkt> pnts { get; set; }

    public graph()
    {
        pnts = new ObservableCollection<punkt>();
        values = new ObservableCollection<double>();
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        pnts.Clear();
        values.Clear();
    }

    public void add_data(double y)
    {
        values.Add(y);

        if (y > maxy)
        {
            maxy = y; OnPropertyChanged("maxy");
            OnPropertyChanged("scale_y");
        }

        if (pnts.Count < width)
        {
            values.Add(y);
            pnts.Add(new pnt(values.Count, y));
        }
        else
        {
            values.Add(y);
            shuffle();
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("pnts");
    }

    public void shuffle()
    {
        pnts = new ObservableCollection<pnt>();

        int s = (int)Math.Ceiling(values.Count / width);

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            if (i % s == 0)
                pnts.Add(new pnt(pnts.Count, values[i]));

        OnPropertyChanged("pnts");
    }

    public void change_width(double new_width)
    {
        width = new_width;
        OnPropertyChanged("width");
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding graph1.scale_y}"/>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding x}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Line X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="{Binding y}" Style="{StaticResource styleGraph}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection and OnPropertyChanged are not related to threading, or Async, they help with DataBinding and View/ViewModel coding. All your work is still being done in one UI thread, so you won't see the changes to your ObservableCollection until it has finished working.

What you need to look at is something like the BackgroundWorker class ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return control to the UI thread each time you update the data so that it can update the UI. You can do this by scheduling your data update tasks on the UI thread `Dispatcher`. You can use a handy method like this:

```
public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```

You can then use this method inside your loop like this:

```
RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
{
    // this will run on the UI thread
    // add your data here
});
```